# A clean way to allow React shared component to get configuraiton property without having to pass it all the way down

Tags: javascript, reactjs, configuration

I have about 8 simple UI's for different applications, all of them make use of a shared components library I also produce.  I recently added a feature to modify how querying is done in the low levels of a some utility functions used in all the saga of all my UIs.

I want each of my UIs to be able to include an optional configuration value to tweak this new querying logic in their configuration files.  However, the method that needs the property is very low level, I'd prefer not to have to add an extra property to 5-6 methods to pass one value down to the method that needs it.

These shared components are used only for my UI, which all have a standard format.  As such I don't need them to be fully generic, I have no complaint with hard coding their checking the standard location of my configuration file in my UIs.  However, since the shared components are a separate NPM package I don't know how to reference the location of a configuration file in the applications calling the UI.

Is there any clean way to get the value from the configuration file other then just passing it through all the relevant methods?

Answer (score 2):

It's simple. You can create configuration file where you'll export your logic. And when you need that config, import that and use. Here's an example:

configuration.js

```
export const test = (myvar) => {
  return 'test: ' + myvar
}
```

component.js

```
import { test } from 'configuration.js'
test('pass') // test: passed
```